# How to check index of string even when the guess word is shorter than the secret word

Tags: python, wordle-game

I am having a really tough time with an error. Every time I input a guess word that is less characters than the secret word, I get "IndexError: string out of range". I am trying to get my code to find the matching letters of the guess word in the secret word. How do I get it to check each index of the word without this error? It doesn't have to print the emoji colors if the character length is less than or greater than 6 letters. I want to keep asking for a new guess until the guess is 6 characters long. I also can only use these basic functions for a class assignment and nothing more than this.

Any help would be appreciated!

```py
WHITE_BOX: str = "\U00002B1C"
GREEN_BOX: str = "\U0001F7E9"
YELLOW_BOX: str = "\U0001F7E8"

secret_word: str = "python"
length_of_secret = len(secret_word)

guess_word: str = input(f"What is your {length_of_secret} letter guess? ")
length_of_guess = len(guess_word)

i: int = 0
check_index: int = 0
emoji_color: str = ""

while check_index < length_of_secret:
    if guess_word[check_index] in secret_word[check_index]:
        emoji_color += GREEN_BOX
    else:
        emoji_color += WHITE_BOX
    check_index += 1

while i < length_of_secret:
    if length_of_guess < length_of_secret:
        guess_word = input(f"That was not {length_of_secret} letters! Try again: ")
        length_of_guess = len(guess_word)
        if guess_word == secret_word:
            print(emoji_color)
            print("Woo! You got it!")
            break
        if length_of_guess == length_of_secret:
            print(emoji_color)
            print("Not quite. Play again soon!")
            break
    if length_of_guess > length_of_secret:
        guess_word = input(f"That was not {length_of_secret} letters! Try again: ")
        length_of_guess = len(guess_word)
        if guess_word == secret_word:
            print(emoji_color)
            print("Woo! You got it!")
            break
        if length_of_guess == length_of_secret:
            print(emoji_color)
            print("Not quite. Play again soon!")
            break
    i += 1
    if guess_word == secret_word:
        print("Woo! You got it!")
        print(emoji_color)
        break
    if length_of_guess == length_of_secret:
        print(emoji_color)
        print("Not quite. Play again soon!")
        break
```

Comment: I've answered your question and edited out code unrelated to the issue at hand. However, in the future, [make sure your that your code is a _minimal_ reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Showing large amounts of  code that is never executed makes it harder for us to identify the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform a length check before analyzing the input string. You should verify your assumption on the length *before* doing anything else that relies on that assumption.

```py
secret_word: str = "python"
length_of_secret = len(secret_word)

guess_word = ""
while len(guess_word) != length_of_secret:
    guess_word: str = input(f"What is your {length_of_secret} letter guess? ")
    if len(guess_word) != length_of_secret:
        print(f"That was not {length_of_secret} letters! Try again.")
```